# How to call method(s) in ruby controller through a script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface

I am really new to web technologies. In my application, I can see that when I click a button on UI, the javascript calls ruby controller and the controller in turn calls method in another ruby file (maybe a file in model, I am not sure) that does some action. I just want to know how can I bypass clicking on UI button and call the controller method from console through a shell or any other script or by any other way and pass it the required arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hit the controller method using simple curl by passing the right http methods and the right url.

Answer (score 0):

From Rails (tried in 3 and 4 releases) console you can do:

```
>> app.get(app.root_path) # app.get("/")
>> app.response.body     
>> app.response.headers  
...
>> app.post(app.edit_user_path(User.last, extram_param: 'foo'))
```

If response is to large, you can redirect it to a file:

```
>> File.open('tmp/response', 'w' ) { |file| file.write(app.response.body) }
```